# Simple PHP: Extract a PHP variable from an array

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I need to get the "shortUrl" element out of this array into a variable but can't !

```
object(stdClass)#1 (4) {
  ["errorCode"]=> int(0) 
  ["errorMessage"]=> string(0) "" 
  ["results"]=> object(stdClass)#2 (1) { 
    ["http://www.domain.com"]=> object(stdClass)#3 (5) { 
      ["userHash"]=> string(6) "oSEMki" 
      ["shortKeywordUrl"]=> string(0) "" 
      ["hash"]=> string(6) "oms2ZB"
      ["shortCNAMEUrl"]=> string(20) "http://bit.ly/LALALA"
      ["shortUrl"]=> string(20) "http://bit.ly/LALALA" 
    } 
  } 
  ["statusCode"]=> string(2) "OK" 
}
```

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its not an array, its an object(-tree).

```
echo $obj->results->{"http://www.domain.com"}->shortUrl;
```

Should work.

Also it looks like you are receiving this structure as JSON I guess? Then you may use the second parameter of [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode) to make an associative array out of it.

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);
echo $array['results']['http://www.domain.com']['shortUrl'];
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It's saved me lots of pain. Instead of "['http://www.domain.com']" I'd like to "$domain" (it's to go inside a loop) but I can't get the syntax correct. Curly braces don't seem to do it. Any ideas welcome !

Comment: Don't know, which variant you are currently using. Its either `$domain = $obj->results->{'http://www.domain.com'}`, or `$domain = $array['results']['http://www.domain.com']`. I suggest you to use the latter one (and remember, that this only works, when you set the second argument of `json_decode()` to `true`!). However, you should read more about arrays and objects in the php manual, because they are both important parts of php.

Comment: I'll read up for sure. I can't get this final bit working. Sorry to ask again. " $domain = $response['results']['$MYVAR']['shortUrl']; " I'm trying to insert a variable where $MYVAR is but the syntax breaks it. Thanks again.

Comment: @Jonathan: You need to adopt KingCrunch's solution.

Comment: @Jonathan: Now you should read about PHPs strings and the different between single quotes `'$var'`, double quotes `"$var"` and (here ;)) no strings at all `$var`. (--> `$response['results'][$MYVAR]`). You should really learn the basics.