# Newbie PHP: Insert a variable for echoing

Tags: php, variables

I'd like to be able to `echo $domain` from this

`$domain = $response['results']['$MYVAR']['shortUrl'];`

I've tried curly braces and various other ways of formatting $MYVAR but the syntax is wrong.

Help most welcome !

EDIT --> var_dump($response):

```
object(stdClass)#1 (4) {
    ["errorCode"]=> int(0)
    ["errorMessage"]=> string(0) ""
    ["results"]=> object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
        ["http://www.domain.com"]=> object(stdClass)#3 (5) {
            ["userHash"]=> string(6) "oSEMki"
            ["shortKeywordUrl"]=> string(0) ""
            ["hash"]=> string(6) "oms2ZB"
            ["shortCNAMEUrl"]=> string(20) "http://bit.ly/LALALA"
            ["shortUrl"]=> string(20) "http://bit.ly/LALALA"
         }
    }
    ["statusCode"]=> string(2) "OK"
}
```

I can see the "domain.com" element fine but when I do this:

var_dump($response['results'][$MYVAR]);

it returns NULL ! Which must be why $domain = $response['results'][$MYVAR]['shortUrl']; fails too. Odd !

--EDIT 2 --

`var_dump($MYVAR);` gives:

`string(118) "http://www.domain.com"`

Comment: I don't see how you can ask this again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6651193/simple-php-extract-a-php-variable-from-an-array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$domain = $response['results'][$MYVAR]['shortUrl'];
echo $domain;
```

Are you sure it's stored in a 3 dimentional array like that?
Because that looks like needless complication.

Comment: @JonathanRoss ah, sorry. Try `var_dump($domain);` and `var_dump($response['results']);` and `var_dump($response['results'][$MYVAR]);` to have a firmer grasp on how they stored their stuff. Echo out $MYVAR to see if that's the correct index name. etc etc..

Comment: @JonathanRoss do this echo `$response->results->shortUrl;`

Comment: @FinalForm: No, you forgot `$MYVAR`

Comment: `echo $response->results->$MYVAR->shortUrl;` is empty too :(

Comment: @phant0m $response->results->$MYVAR->shortUrl;

Comment: @JonathanRoss var_dump($response->results); and i want you to echo out $MYVAR

Comment: @Jonathan: Then you should check the contents of $MYVAR. @FinalForm: I know, it's been in my answer for a couple of minutes ;)

Comment: @phant0m I REMEMBER YOU! I have surpassed you in points. muahahah :-p

Comment: @JonathanRoss Just break the problem into smaller pieces, echo out or var_dump the variables and see what the problem is, debug man. I believe in you. :-p

Comment: @FinalForm: haha, that's only because you're lucky

Comment: @phant0m LUCKILY AWESOME YOU MEAN :-) :-p

Comment: @JonathanRoss when you var_dumped that sucker, it shows it as being an object, it even says object. but you're trying to access the thing like it's an array, use ->, arrow guy.

Comment: @JonathanRoss gotta teach you to debug better. Yes, that's empty, but what about when you `var_dump($response->results->$MYVAR):`? Break the problem into smaller/simpler pieces.

Comment: @JonathanRoss now keep debugging guy. What about when you var_dump($response->results); ?  I want you to also do `echo $MYVAR;` and tell me what the results are from that. Are you beginning to see how I'm just breaking the problem into smaller/simpler pieces to see where the problem is?

Comment: @FinalForm: It's in the question.

Comment: echo $MYVAR is as expected `http://www.domain.com` `var_dump($response->results);` is "NULL".

Comment: @JonathanRoss something is amiss, are you leaving out code? Like code in between where you var_dump and where the variable exists? I'm deducing the answer is yes, because the above statement you just made doesn't make sense.

Comment: @phant0m BAM baby, problem fixed. it was his regex. :-p

Comment: @phant0m REGEX that was in the rest of his code that I got to see ;-p The problem was not in the code he pasted. See my earlier comment, I deduced correctly the issue was not in the code he pasted from his comments. CLEVER DEDUCTION baby

Comment: @phant0m eh, just being friendly to you, sorry, voice intonation is lost over written text. I'm saying these with a friendly competitive tone.

Answer (score 1):

Try it without quotes

```
$domain = $response['results'][$MYVAR]['shortUrl'];
```

or use double quotes

```
$domain = $response['results']["$MYVAR"]['shortUrl'];
```

EDIT:

In reaction to your edit. You are accessing variable like an associative array but the variable is instance of stdObject. So if you want to acces it, you must retype it like this:

```
$tmp = (array) $response;
$domain = $tmp['results'][$MYVAR]['shortUrl'];
```

or access it like object

```
$domain = $tmp->results->$MYWAR->shortUrl;
```

EDIT 2:

So it is strange, because `http://www.domain.com` is not 118 characters long, as var_dump wrote.

Where and how did you filled up the variable `$MYVAR`?

Comment: Give me the output of var_dump($MYVAR) pls.

Comment: Formatting is borked. I'll put it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
$domain = $response['results'][$MYVAR]['shortUrl'];
```

You don't need quotes around $MYVAR.

Comment: Still not getting it unfortunately: `$domain = $response['results'][$MYVAR]['shortUrl']; echo $domain;` $MYVAR is a URL and works like `['http://domain.com']` but not as [$MYVAR].

Comment: Try print_r($response). That will help you see the entire arrays keys and values.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried without the quotes around $MYVAR?

Answer (score 0):

It's an object.

```
$domain = $response->results->$MYVAR->shortUrl;
```